# Check Date between two date columns from two dates mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check that record exist or not.

**Table1:**

```
  S.No    StartDate         EndDate
 -------------------------------------
  1.      2019-10-15        2019-10-20
  2.      2019-10-10        2019-10-13
  3.      2019-10-21        2019-10-25
```

I need to get data if any of the condition gets true according to any below scenarios.

**Case 1:**
If date_from: **2019-10-17** and date_to: **2019-10-19**

Output:

```
  S.No    StartDate         EndDate
 -------------------------------------
  1.      2019-10-15        2019-10-20
```

**Case 2:**
If date_from: **2019-10-14** and date_to: **2019-10-21**

Output:

```
  S.No    StartDate         EndDate
 -------------------------------------
  1.      2019-10-15        2019-10-20
  3.      2019-10-21        2019-10-25
```

**Case 3:**
If date_from: **2019-10-13** and date_to: **2019-10-16**

Output:

```
  S.No    StartDate         EndDate
 -------------------------------------
  1.      2019-10-15        2019-10-20
  2.      2019-10-10        2019-10-13
```

**Case 4:**
If date_from: **2019-10-17** and date_to: **2019-10-20**

Output:

```
  S.No    StartDate         EndDate
 -------------------------------------
  1.      2019-10-15        2019-10-20
```

**Case 5:**
If date_from: **2019-11-17** and date_to: **2019-11-20**

Output:

```
  *No records
```

Here what I had tried:

Query1:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN **date_from** AND **date_to**
OR EndDate BETWEEN **date_from** AND **date_to**
```

Query2:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE **date_from** BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate 
OR **date_to** BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
```

I had already tried below solutions:

[Check two date was not between two another date + MYSQl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865807/check-two-date-was-not-between-two-another-date-mysql)

[check given date exists between two date column in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621325/check-given-date-exists-between-two-date-column-in-mysql)

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is the overlapping date range problem.  Here is a query for your first scenario, where you want to find matching records between `2019-10-17` and `2019-10-19`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE EndDate >= '2019-10-17' AND StartDate <= '2019-10-19';
```

More generally:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE EndDate >= <date_from> AND StartDate <= <date_to>;
```

If you wanted to include say two date ranges in a single query, then you may simply expand the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (EndDate >= '2019-10-13' AND StartDate <= '2019-10-16') OR
    (EndDate >= '2019-10-17' AND StartDate <= '2019-10-19');
```

Comment: Thanks! but is there any other way that I can achieve all outputs using a single query.

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind here.  If you want to handle multiple start/end pairs, then you may expand my `WHERE` clause via an `OR`.

Comment: This scenario is meant for booking system, need to check that **is there any booking between given two dates?**

Comment: I have already answered that question.  If my query leaves out something you need, then state what that is.

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes!
a user can pass any input from above 5.
I need to handle all cases with a single query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  a user can pass any input from above 5. I need to handle all cases with a single query

Comment: yes, I tried Tim's query and made some modifications and that took me to the solution.

Comment: @MohitGupta . . . Tim's solution is the best way to solve your problem.  I would advise you to delete your answer and accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me for all the above cases

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE ( StartDate <= 'date_from' and EndDate >= 'date_from' )
OR ( 'date_from' <= StartDate and 'date_to' >= StartDate )
OR ( StartDate < 'date_to' and EndDate >= 'date_to' )
```

Reference:

[SQL query to search for room availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213183/sql-query-to-search-for-room-availability)

Comment: It was pointless for you to post this answer IMHO.  It doesn't explain how you got to this answer, and it won't be very helpful for other readers.